# ormlite available connection error after hold down F5

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have a web application and data service application for that with service stack. When I browse main page (queries the data service) and hold down F5 button a little time then connection is closed.

"ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

Adding OrmLiteConnectionFactory like this;

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ApplicationConfigGlobal.DbConnString, SqlServerDialect.Provider)).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

Our repo implementation

```
public class BaseRepository : IDisposable
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    private IDbConnection _dbConn;
    protected IDbConnection DbConn
    {
        get
        {
            return _dbConn ?? (_dbConn = DbFactory.Open());
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_dbConn != null)
            _dbConn.Dispose();
    }
```

In your opinion Which detail i'm missing?

We have done a workaround like below. But we didn't test it in production environment yet.

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public IDbConnection DbConn
    {
        get
        {
            var conn = Container.TryResolve<IDbConnection>();
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Open();
            }
            return conn;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Not sure on this, but are you disposing of your repository after using it? If not then the database connection would also not be disposed.

Comment: Did you manage to make any progress on this?  I too get this error, and it feels like it is due to load/frequent calls.

Comment: did you notice my edit?